# Correct EMAIL Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a table with an email field this field can only have the following characters:

'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789. @ _- +'

How can you check the email field to know if I have any different characters from the ones I mentioned ('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789. @ _- +')?

Comment: Valid patterns for email addresses are quite complicated. There is an entire website dedicated to [email regexes](https://emailregex.com/).

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect job for a regular expression - just check whether the E-Mail contains any characters that are not in your list. You can use `regexp_like` for this:

```
regexp_like(e_mail, '[^-a-z0-9.@_ +]')
```

(I've replaced a...z and 0..9 with the respective ranges - shorter and more readable. Note that the hyphen '-' has to be the first character after the initial caret '^' to indicate that it is a literal hyphen and not part of a character range).

Simple test case:

```
with v_data(e_mail) as (
  select 'xyz@abc.com' from dual union all
  select 'xyz(@def.com' from dual union all
  select 'ab123-def@gmail.com' from dual
)
select 
  e_mail,
  (case 
     when regexp_like(e_mail, '[^-a-z0-9.@_ +]') then 'NO' 
     else 'YES' 
   end) as is_valid_email
from v_data
```

However, a valid E-Mail adresse can contain tons of additional characters - uppercase letters for example.

Comment: 253/5000
thanks,

I have tried what you tell me but I have the following problem

The emails equal to xxx-xxxx@gmail.com or xxx-xxxxxx@hotmail.com for giving some examples mark them as NO

this is not correct because the '-' character is among the valid ones.

Comment: You're right, I forgot about the special role of  '-' within square brackets. There, it denotes a character range. Fixed it.